# Switching storyboard view controller in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to switch to different ViewController on same storyboard like so:

CalendarViewController *CalViewController = [[CalendarViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:CalViewController animated:NO completion:nil];

When I run this action, corresponding implementation file executes NSLog message but screen goes black with no errors being displayed.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you created your CalendarViewController interface in a storyboard, and you assigned it the identifier "ControllerIdentifier".

If you want to load it from inside another View Controller, you can instantiate your CalendarViewController and present it like this:

```
CalendarViewController *calViewController = (CalendarViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerIdentifier"]
[self presentViewController:calViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Segue to push calViewController.
2. You can use the code below;

   `CalendarViewController *CalViewController = (CalendarViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CalendarViewControllerIdentifier"];
   [self presentViewController:CalViewController animated:NO completion:nil];`

But if you choose the second option, you have to set CalendarViewController's Storyboard Identifier to CalendarViewControllerIdentifier from your storyboard.