# loading a view manually objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Lets say I am in ViewController1 and I want to load ViewController2. The only way I know to accomplish this is using a button in ViewController1, and connecting to ViewController2 in the storyboard but I do not want to do it that way. I want to do in a method in MyViewController1. For example, in my viewDidLoad method.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: it seems a duplicate to 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077933/switching-storyboard-view-controller-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

Create a segue from vc1 to vc2 inside the storyboard, give it a name and call:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"mySegueCustomName" sender: self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse Views and ViewControllers. You post title suggests you do not have it ingrained yet fully.

If you want to present another view controller programatically, then simply create an action method for the button and do it there. ViewDidLoad is absolutely **NOT fit** for that purpose.

You can present a view controller included in the storyboard like this:

```
-(IBAction)goToDetails:(id)sender
{
    //identify the correct storyboard
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard's name" bundle:nil];

    //extract a  view controller instance from the storyboard
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"details view controller's identifier"];

    //present the view controller instance
    [self presentViewController:detailViewController
                       animated:YES
                    completion:nil];
}
```

And here's an example to go a to an unrelated non-storyboard view controller.

```
-(IBAction)loginToSystem:(id)sender
{
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

    [self presentViewController:loginViewController 
                       animated:YES 
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: The ViewController is in a Storyboard, so that's not gonna work. he need https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

Comment: @RatulSharker The OP didn't say it is in the storyboard.

Comment: the question says "ViewController2 in the storyboard". That's why i was suggesting [storyboard instantiate.....

Comment: @RatulSharker " in the storyboard but I do not want to do it that way"

Comment: He means without using storyboard's segue i guess :), still keeping the Viewcontroller2 in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to embed the view managed by ViewController2 into the view managed by ViewController1, you can do this by adding a UIContainerView to ViewController1 with an embed segue pointing to ViewController2.

This is useful, for example, if you have a reusable view managed by ViewController2 and want to use that in multiple places.

You can do this in InterfaceBuilder by dragging a UIContainerView from the Object library onto the view for ViewController1. You can then change the class of the view controller it creates to ViewController2.